# Quantile Function for a Vector of Dates

Tags: r, sorting, date

I noticed that the base R `quantile` function does not support date arguments.

I appreciate that defining quantiles for dates needs care in the definitions (i.e. if you have 6 dates and ask for the 25th percentile, you need to define the suitable rounding).

Is there an efficient implementation of such a quantile function, either as a part of base or another package.

The following sample function achieves essentially what I am interested in (with some tweaking to handle the case of the 0'th percentile), but I imagine that more efficient implementations are possible.

```
#Date quantile function.
dquantile <- function(x, probs){

  sx <- sort(x)

  pos <- round( probs * length(x) )

  return( sx[pos] )
}

# Example.
dates <- as.Date("01/01/1900", "%d/%m/%Y") + floor( 36500 * runif(100000) )

dquantile(dates, c(0.001, 0.025, 0.975, 0.999) )
```

Comment: Your assumption is that you have a sample of dates from a date population. I think you can often coerce your dates to, e.g., durations or days since a starting date.

Comment: Yes I agree, I'm not overly familiar / confident with R's syntax for date manipulation / converting between dates and numerics. That's why I wrote my example above in a way that allows R to handle internally the manipulation of date objects. Definitely acknowledge it is sub-optimal. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `x` is a vector of Dates and `probs` is a vector of probabilities:

```
# test input
x <- as.Date("2018-03-21") + 0:10
probs <- 1:9/10

as.Date(quantile(unclass(x), probs), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

giving:

```
         10%          20%          30%          40%          50%          60% 
"2018-03-22" "2018-03-23" "2018-03-24" "2018-03-25" "2018-03-26" "2018-03-27" 
         70%          80%          90% 
"2018-03-28" "2018-03-29" "2018-03-30"
```

Answer (score 21):

The `quantile` function does support dates, you just need to specify the `type` argument. Your problem can be solved with:

```
dates <- as.Date("01/01/1900", "%d/%m/%Y") + floor( 36500 * runif(100000) )

quantile(dates, probs = c(0.001, 0.025, 0.975, 0.999), type = 1)

        0.1%         2.5%        97.5%        99.9% 
"1900-02-04" "1902-06-23" "1997-06-10" "1999-10-30"
```